# Why isn't PHP filesize() function working?

Tags: php

I noticed that filesize doesn't work when I'm trying to list the contents of a directory using a path like this:

```
../
```

for example this works:

```
if ($handle = opendir('./')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

            echo "File Name: $file | File Size: ". filesize($file)."<br />";            

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
if ($handle = opendir('../')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

            echo "File Name: $file | File Size: ". filesize($file)."<br />";            

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

In the last example the file names are listed fine but instead of getting their file size I get this error:

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for dynamic.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\app_file_manager\panel\index.php on line 65
```

Is there a way to get the 2nd example to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`filesize($file)` is failing because the `$file` is the name of the file that exists in the parent directory and not in the current directory.

You need to prefix `$file` with `../`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define a variable like `$basepath` or `$downloads` folder path and append the filename to that variable and use `filesize()`. Be sure to avoid `./`  and `../`.

```
$downloads = "www/base/downloads"; 
$filepath = $downloads."/".$filename;
filesize($filepath)
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, problem might be in:

- If file corrupted (`[function.filesize]: stat failed` error most offen occurs with file uploaders)
- In linux 32-bit this error will be for files that are larger 2GB